# Virtual attributes from define_method generated methods in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes, ruby-on-rails-2

I have methods for getting and setting virtual attributes. Actually they set one character on a real attribute as this code snippet should explain:

```
attr_accessible :picnic_on_sunday, :picnic_on_monday, :picnic_on_tuesday,
                :picnic_on_wednesday, :picnic_on_thursday, :picnic_on_friday,
                :picnic_on_saturday,

['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday',
  'friday', 'saturday'].each_with_index do |dayname, dayindex|
  define_method "picnic_on_#{dayname.downcase}".to_sym do
    picnic_weekdays[dayindex]=='1'
  end
  define_method "picnic_on_#{dayname.downcase}=" do |value|
    wdays = picnic_weekdays
    wdays[dayindex] = (value==true or value=='1') ? '1':'0'
    self.picnic_weekdays = wdays 
  end
end
```

`picnic_weekdays` is a real attribute present in the scheme. My problem is that although the generated getters/setters work when I make changes, `x.picnic_on_monday = true` changes the index 1 on `x.picnic_weekdays`, nothing is saved when I call `save` on the model. This behavior is only when the methods are generated by `define_method`. Why is it so? How can I make the generated virtual attributes working? Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: It might be worth a try to add attr_accessible :picnic_weekdays if you haven't already.

Comment: Yes, I tries that already and the same result. Although I solved actually the problem other way, but it still interests me why this construct does not work as I would expect.. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: You are implementing a bit field, but there are a couple of conceptual errors in the code. I would personally not do this myself, but use a plugin. https://github.com/xing/flag_shih_tzu does exactly what you want. It's well tested and well maintained.

Comment: @baaij thanks for the hint! it is worth of checking it out. which are the conceptual errors you are referring to? Maybe just bing more specific about them would give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The change that you're making to `picnic_weekdays` is not persistent is because you appear to have defeated the internal logic in ActiveRecord that keeps track of the attributes that have changed!  My guess is that it is due to the way that the Dirty module is patched into ActiveRecord.

The example in your question can be fixed by telling ActiveRecord that the attribute has changed by using the `<attribute>_will_change!` method as follows:

```
define_method "picnic_on_#{dayname.downcase}=" do |value|
  wdays = picnic_weekdays
  wdays[dayindex] = (value==true or value=='1') ? '1':'0'
  self.picnic_weekdays = wdays 
  self.picnic_weekdays_will_change!
end
```

Comment: great explanation, worth of trying and it sounds like an answer. thank you!